# What's the right place to get a test wallet

Tags: testnet, faucet

Sorry for the n00b question.

I'm following along here: https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/

And the first step to play around seems to be to get a test wallet from "Faucet", which links to https://faucet.tzalpha.net, except that that link is broken.

Is this a known thing? Is the doc outdated? Is there a *new* place I should go to get a test wallet? Am I just following along outdated instructions?

*Thanks*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new faucet links are available here: https://teztnets.xyz

Comment: Thanks, will use this instead!